# https request with client certificate return access denied in android but it works good in post man , retrofit and okhttp3 return the same error

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, client

iam trying to post https request with okhttp3 or retrofit2 with client ssl certificate added locally in android raw dir as .pfx file but web api return with access denied and response code 403 but same scenario works good in postman

```
public class OkhttpManager {
static private OkhttpManager mOkhttpManager=null;
private InputStream mTrustrCertificate;
OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

static public OkhttpManager getInstance()
{
    if(mOkhttpManager==null)
    {
        mOkhttpManager=new OkhttpManager();
    }
    return mOkhttpManager;
 }

 private X509TrustManager trustManagerForCertificates(InputStream in)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {

    // Use it to build an X509 trust manager.
    char[] password = "123456".toCharArray();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    try {
        keyStore.load(getTrustrCertificates(),password);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory  =KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
    }
    return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
}

public void setTrustrCertificates(InputStream ic)
{
    mTrustrCertificate = ic;
}

public InputStream getTrustrCertificates()
{
    return mTrustrCertificate;
}

public OkHttpClient build()
{
    List<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<>();
    protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);

    if(getTrustrCertificates()!=null)
    {
        X509TrustManager trustManager;
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
        try {
            trustManager = trustManagerForCertificates(getTrustrCertificates());
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
            sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        List<ConnectionSpec> connectionSpecs = new LinkedList<>();
        ConnectionSpec strict = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_3, TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .build();
        connectionSpecs.add(strict);

     okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
                .addInterceptor(new SslCertificateLogger())
                .protocols(protocols)
                .connectionSpecs(connectionSpecs)
                .readTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(45,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                        if (s.equals("my host name")){
                            return true;
                        }else
                            return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();


    }
    else
    {

        okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(45,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .protocols(protocols)
                .build();

    }
    return okHttpClient;
}}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

here how to call okhttpmanager and make okhttp3 request

```
 void postRequest(String postUrl,String postBody) throws IOException {

    OkhttpManager client = new OkhttpManager();

    try {
        InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
        OkhttpManager.getInstance().setTrustrCertificates(caInput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, postBody);

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(postUrl)
            .post(body)
            .build();

    request.header("Content-type : application/json; charset=utf-8");


    client.build().newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d("TAG", response.body().string());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    </application>
```

enable it in Manifest